# Access a button from Recyclerview in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a heterogeneous `RecyclerView` that has a `header`. In it I have a button. What I would like to do is change that button's properties (background, text) from my `Fragment`. Basically, when an API call is finished and there's a response, I need to somehow notify the `adapter` to change the background and text of the button. But, I can't seem to get the idea on how to get that button's reference or where to put the code for changing button's properties.

`Recyclerview`

```
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);

        switch (viewType) {
            case HEADER_TYPE:
                View viewHeader = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_profile_header, parent, false);
                StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams lp1 = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager.LayoutParams) viewHeader.getLayoutParams();
                lp1.setFullSpan(true);
                viewHeader.setLayoutParams(lp1);
                return new ProfileAdapter.HeaderHolder(viewHeader);

@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        switch (holder.getItemViewType()) {
            case HEADER_TYPE:
                onBind = true;
                bindHeader((ProfileAdapter.HeaderHolder) holder, mHomeList.get(position));
                onBind = false;
                break;

private void bindHeader(final ProfileAdapter.HeaderHolder holder, Home home) {
        holder.mItemProfileHeaderBinding.setHome(home);
        holder.getItemProfileHeaderBinding().btnFollow.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (mListener == null) {
                return;
            }
            mListener.onClickFollow();
        });
    }
```

`Fragment`

```
if (response.getResponseInfo().getStatus() != 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Profile problem: " + response.getResponseInfo().getMessage());
        } else {
    //How to do some sort of callback here?
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your filling your header with data add extra Fields for background, size and anything else those fields will design the header as needed for the situation and then when you need to change the header just change the list of the adapter and call notify item changed on the header

Comment: I will accept this because it gave me and idea of how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `interface` and then have your fragment `implement` it. I'm using the following in my adapter

**adapter.java**

```
public interface OnClickRecyclerChild {
    void myCallback(String s);
}
```

I attach my OnClickRecyclerChild when I call my constructor

**adapter.java**

```
public adapter(List<bindableAssignment> dataBaseItemList, OnClickRecyclerChild mCallback) {
    this.mCallback = mCallback;
    this.dataBaseItemList = dataBaseItemList;
}
```

So when you call your create your adapter you can give it an interface like so

```
mAdapter = new adapter(new ArrayList<bindableAssignment>(), new adapter.OnClickRecyclerChild() {
        @Override
        public void myCallback(String s) {
            Log.d(TAG,s);
        }
    });
```

The code inside the `myCallback(String s)` will run when you call mCallback.myCallback(String) anywhere in your adapter.

Comment: Hmm this way I can't really access the `button` and change its properties from my `fragment`.